# How can I insert data to MongoDB from Next JS page without api?

Tags: mongodb, next.js, crud

Hi I was trying to post/insert data from next js page to mongodb. I want to learn CRUD with out any api implementations. I was able to get data with `getServerSideProps`but I can't post any data to mongodb. I am using next-os's `with-mongodb` example.

```
  const [username, setUsername] = useState();
  const handleChangeUsername = (event) => {
    setUsername(e.target.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  };
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    console.log(username);
    if (await db.collection("users").insertOne({username:})) {
      console.log("done");
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  };
```

Comment: Don't do that. It will make your app insecure, lots of connection to database will make it less efficient and vulnerable.

Comment: So are you suggesting to go with apis? @MostafizRahman

Comment: yes, you should use API